# Bundle-price is shown as 0 in minicart

Tags: price, bundled-product, mini-cart

if I put a bundled product into my cart, I do get displayed this correctly in the minicart-preview but the pricing is always on "0". On the other hand, if I head forward to the carts' summary-page (and all other checkout-steps )the price is shown totally correctly. So I guess, the value is used/pushed correctly, just not getting displayed correctly in the minicart.

I use getFinalPrice to display the pricing and it displays anything correctly for configurable and simple products. This is the code I am using:

```
$finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');
$finalPrice += $this->getTotalBundleItemsPrice($product, $qty); 
$finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);
```

as recommended here http://gielberkers.com/how-to-calculate-prices-for-bundled-products-in-magento/ Where would be a good point to check what's wrong? Could I have forgotten a check on the dashboard?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the product price or try to calculate it in the mini cart, instead use the already calculated item price from the quote. I assume you loop over `$quote->getAllVisibleItems()` and `$item` is the current item:

```
$item->getPriceInclTax()
```

You will see the parts of the bundle with their prices